# vertically distributing divs in a responsive site

Tags: javascript, css

first-time poster - I'll try to fit in :)
I have a div on the left of my page at width 75% and a sidebar on the right with four divs in a vertical column. I would like those sidebar divs distributed evenly with the height of the main div, as the window resizes. Obviously, as it does so, the main div's content will dictate that height.

I have managed this with the below script. I don't know if it is the most elegant solution, or the most sensible, but it seems to work for me!

```
var mrrHeight = document.getElementById('mrrBody').clientHeight;
document.getElementById("side1").style.height = (mrrHeight/4)-21 + "px";
document.getElementById("side2").style.height = (mrrHeight/4)-21 + "px";
document.getElementById("side3").style.height = (mrrHeight/4)-21 + "px";
document.getElementById("side4").style.height = (mrrHeight/4)-21 + "px";
```

Now I need to get it to work in a more real-time manner - at present it only works on load and the sidebar divs are the wrong size when the window is resized. Generally, that is (almost) acceptable - it works on different sized devices, but I'll look a bit silly the day someone resizes their browser window and the layout screws up. Would I use a listener, and where would I put it? I figured out that my script HAS to be after the mrrBody div.

I could probably get the right result using tables, but "In general, web developers consider table-based layout a taboo" - is that making my life unnecessarily difficult for myself? I started using divs in my site precisely to get away from my old table-based layout!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a flex based layout. Your 75% width container and the side bar container would live inside a wrapping container with flex properties. The side bar would also use flex properties. No JS needed. The right column items would resize based on the content of the left.

```css
.flex-wrap {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.left {
  height: 500px;
  width: 75%;
  display: flex;
}

.left-inner {
  background: blue;
  border-radius: 6px;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.left, .right {
  padding: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.right {
  flex: 1;

  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.side-content-box {
  flex-grow: 1;
  padding: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
}

.inner {
  border-radius: 6px;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 8px #000;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-wrap">
  <div class="left">
    <div class="left-inner">
    hi
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <div class="side-content-box">
     <div class="inner"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="side-content-box">
      <div class="inner"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="side-content-box">
      <div class="inner"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="side-content-box">
      <div class="inner"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for that - I'd seen reference to flex while researching my problem, but was slightly put off by less than ideal browser support i.e. IE Is there an acceptable polyfill or would I have to use a fallback that would mess up my hard-won layout?

Comment: if I don't care too much about IE (which I frankly stopped doing ages ago!) and other older browsers, I'd be happy to use flex. I neglected to mention that my sidebar divs have rounded borders with shadows so a straight implementation of flex cramps them together, but I worked around it by adding a margin. They no longer distribute exactly to the top/bottom, but it might be close enough.

Comment: @mattyniner I updated the code snippet to include rounded corners and a box shadow.

Comment: sweet - I also added 5px margin top and bottom to .left and that seems to line the two sides up evenly at top & bottom :)
That works, I think?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `window.onresize` event:

```
window.onresize = function(event) {
    var mrrHeight = document.getElementById('mrrBody').clientHeight;
    document.getElementById("side1").style.height = (mrrHeight/4)-21 + "px";
    document.getElementById("side2").style.height = (mrrHeight/4)-21 + "px";
    document.getElementById("side3").style.height = (mrrHeight/4)-21 + "px";
    document.getElementById("side4").style.height = (mrrHeight/4)-21 + "px";
};
```

Comment: it _seems_ like what I'd need, but I can't figure out why this doesn't work for me. I've tried this in place of my original code, in addition to it in the html body and also in the head but none of them have any effect on the divs on resize. Pardon my ignorance if I'm missing something blindingly obvious!
As an aside, if I have to use it twice, should I save the var mrrHeight etc as an external script and call it when I need it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a flex `column` layout for this, and set the divs you want to be evenly distributed to `flex: 1 0 0` so they will `flex-grow` to fill the parent.

```css
* {margin:0;}
  
aside {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 25vw;
}

aside > div {
  flex: 1 0 0;
  background: #09c;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}
```

```html
<aside>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</aside>
```